# VSCode debugger exclude node VM files

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, v8

When stepping through javascript code running in Node.js v8.4.0 using VSCode's debugger utility, the debugger enters files titled VMXXXX (e.g. `VM1550`). Note the `ret` function on the top of the call stack in the attached screenshot.

What path should be placed in `skipFiles` array in the `launch.json` configuration such that these non-userland source files be excluded from VSCode's debug stepping.

I already have the node internals excluded as per the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging).

```
"skipFiles": [
  "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: We don't have a skipFiles option for VM scripts, but you could file a feature request on github. These come from scripts that were created with `eval()`

Comment: has there been any solution to ignore vm files ? this has been an awful lot of problem for me lately.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet :(

Comment: @Hafizallylalani What do you mean with ` vm` files ?

Comment: I just tested with node v10.16.3 and this is working. (I actually needed to stop on VM, so I removed the skipFiles entry).